# Java LibGDX Multi Touch Issue

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
    for (byte i = 0; i < 20; i++) {maxDistance = 10 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i) && Gdx.input.getY()<= 400) {
            player1TouchPosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0);
            camera.unproject(player1TouchPosition);
        }
        player1Tmp.set(player1TouchPosition.x, player1TouchPosition.y).sub(player1Rectangle.x, player1Rectangle.y);
        if (player1Tmp.len() <= maxDistance) {
            player1Rectangle.x = player1TouchPosition.x;
            player1Rectangle.y = player1TouchPosition.y;
        } else {
            player1Tmp.nor().scl(maxDistance);
            player1Rectangle.x += player1Tmp.x;
            player1Rectangle.y += player1Tmp.y;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i) && Gdx.input.getY() >= 401) {
            player2TouchPosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0);
            camera.unproject(player2TouchPosition);
        }
        player2Tmp.set(player2TouchPosition.x, player2TouchPosition.y).sub(player2Rectangle.x, player2Rectangle.y);
        if (player2Tmp.len() <= maxDistance) {
            player2Rectangle.x = player2TouchPosition.x;
            player2Rectangle.y = player2TouchPosition.y;
        } else {
            player2Tmp.nor().scl(maxDistance);
            player2Rectangle.x += player2Tmp.x;
            player2Rectangle.y += player2Tmp.y;
        }
    }
```

Hello I'm using this code to move to touch position. But I need multi touch. It's not working. When I add player2, it doesn't work. I didn't understand how is multi touch. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not use InputProcessor?
One example of one method from the interface

```
 @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if(pointer =< 2){
            touches.get(pointer).touchX = screenX;
            touches.get(pointer).touchY = screenY;
            touches.get(pointer).touched = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In the above example you can use maximum 2 touches.
Actually 1 pointer is 1 touch.

[Documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html)

`screenX` and `screenY` are the touch position. Be aware you have to scale this position compared to your orthographic camera. A pointer is the pointer for the event.

If you create the `InputProcessor` you can launch it with

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(/*Your class*/);
```

**EDIT:**

Example from the comments:

```
for (Button button : /*ArrayList*/{
            if (positionX >= button1.getX() && positionX <= button1.getX() + button1.getWidth() &&
                    positionY >= button1.getY() && positionY <= button1.getY() + button1.getHeight()){
        //Update the position from the specific button
}
```

You use this code inside the method from the interface `touchDragged()`.

Comment: You have 2 rectangles, 1 rectangle up and 1 down. So first you check if the position is up or down. I prefer to use `touchDragged` instead of `touchDown`. `touchDragged` is also a method from the interface `InputProcessor`.

Comment: After that you initialize the variable for rectangle 1 and rectangle 2. In the render method you have to update the new position.

Comment: I hope I've helped you! :)

Comment: You can do that with only one `InputProcessor`. What I would do: Make a class `Button` that hold the following information: positionX, positionY, width and height. After that you make an `ArrayList` with as generic type `Button`. In the `touchDragged` method you make a foreach loop that iterate through the `ArrayList`. In the body from the foreach loop you will check wheter the Button is clicked like that: